# Login to GKE via service account with token

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to access my Kubernetes cluster on google cloud with the service account, but I am not able to make this works.  I have a running system with some pods and ingress. I want to be able to update images of deployments.

I would like to use something like this (remotely):

```
kubectl config set-cluster cluster --server="<IP>" --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config set-credentials foo --token="<TOKEN>"
kubectl config set-context my-context --cluster=cluster --user=foo --namespace=default
kubectl config use-context cluster
kubectl set image deployment/my-deployment boo=eu.gcr.io/project-123456/image:v1
```

So I created the service account and then get the secret token:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount foo
kubectl get secret foo-token-gqvgn -o yaml
```

But, when I try to update the image in any deployment, I receive:

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

IP address for API I use the address, which is shown in GKE administration as cluster endpoint IP.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to recreate your problem.

Steps I have followed

- `kubectl create serviceaccount foo`
- `kubectl get secret foo-token-* -o yaml`

Then, I have tried to do what you have done

**What I have used** as token is `base64` decoded Token.

Then I tried this:

```
$ kubectl get pods
```

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:foo" cannot list pods in the namespace "default": Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:default:foo"

This gave me error as expected. Because, I need to grant permission to this ServiceAccount.

**How can I grant permission** to this ServiceAccount? I need to create ClusterRole & ClusterRoleBinding with necessary permission.

Read more to learn more [role-based-access-control](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control)

### I can do another thing

```
$ kubectl config set-credentials foo --username="admin" --password="$PASSWORD"
```

This will grant you admin authorization.

You need to provide cluster credential.

```
Username: admin
Password: -----
```

You will get this info in GKE -> Kubernetes Engine -> {cluster} -> Show credential

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Before I already played with roles. But in your answer is a solution for me - and it is simple! I didn't decode the token from base64 to plain text. Now it is working. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that the * doesn't work 

`kubectl get secret` this will give you the list then you just need to copy paste